# Glassfish and Nginx: 2 apps in 2 different locations

Tags: nginx, glassfish

I am really a nginx newbie so please excuse the mistakes etc.

The domain: http://www.example.com

The 2 glassfish apps:

http://localhost:8080/app1
http://localhost:8080/app2

What I'd like:

Glassfish app1 served at:
http://www.example.com

Glassfish app2 served at:
http://www.example.com/app2

At the moment I have:

```
server {
    listen       80;
   server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080/app1/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;
        proxy_pass_header Host;    }

    location /app2/ {

        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080/app2/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;
        proxy_pass_header Host;    }
}
```

But the paths get mixed up: when I do "http://example.com/app2" this is "http://example.com/app1" which comes out.

Help?

Comment: Please expand on the error you are encountering

Comment: Just edited to describe the nature of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a redirection issue which may or may not be solvable by `nginx` alone.

Applications often issue a redirect to their controller, and if app2 thinks it is in the root, it might issue a redirect to `/` which will immediately be forwarded to app1.

You need to look at the redirection headers and determine if you can put a `proxy_redirect` into your location container in order to fix the problem.

You also need to consider if app1 and app2 can function within a subdirectory. For example, do they access CSS and JS files with a relative or absolute path. These references cannot be corrected by `nginx`.

Comment: Thanks! I just don't know what a redirection header is, and where to examine it?

Comment: I use `Live HTTP headers` add-on with firefox to inspect the `Location:` header in the http response.

Comment: The incoming request is from a 301 redirect: I wonder if that would explain the mess? I googled about "how to treat 301 redirects arriving on a nginx server" but could not find it discussed.

Comment: Those are easy to fix. Take a look at [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect). You need to add a `proxy_redirect what_it_wants_to_do what_you_want_it_to_do;`